# Alert box when no internet connection - Phonegap

Tags: cordova, connection, alert

I'm trying to get a pop-up to, well, pop up when there is no internet connection on the device.

I got [the following example](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.0.0/phonegap_connection_connection.md.html) working, but now I want the alert only to show when the result is "No network connection".

I tried this:

```
if (states[Connection.NONE]){
       alert('Geen internet :(');
       };
```

But that just makes the alert-box pop up, no matter if there is a connection or not.
Who can help me? :)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Old-ish question, but here's how I'd do it - You can use events to detect if the device is online or offline. This is ideal for this situation as the pop-up will appear as soon as the device goes offline:

`document.addEventListener("offline", function(){ alert("You're offline") }, false);`

And to do the same, but when the device regains an internet connection?:

`document.addEventListener("online", function(){ alert("You're online") }, false);`

Check out the events docs here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.1/cordova_events_events.md.html#offline

**UPDATE :**

as of cordova 5 these events have been moved to [cordova-plugin-network-information](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-network-information)

Comment: Came by this question by coincidence and noticed I never marked an answer as correct. This seems the easiest and best anser, thanks!

Comment: This is great but I'd like to know the state when the app initially starts - is there any way of getting that in the same sort of way?

Comment: Does anyone face the issue that I face - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35425746/cordova-network-information-plugin-regularly-show-offline-unknown-state?noredirect=1#comment58568671_35425746

Comment: I find these methods to be highly inconsistent when using Cordova. Sometimes the it says connection none even though one exist.

Answer (score 7):

if you do

```
if (states[Connection.NONE]){
   alert('Geen internet :(');
   };
```

this would happen. 

do this.

```
networkState = navigator.network.connection.type
alert(states[networkState]);
```

see if this works for u or not.

**EDIT:**  just compare:

```
if (networkState == Connection.NONE){
  alert('no internet ');
};
```

Comment: That does exactly what the example does: returning the kind of connection in an alert-box.
What I want is that the pop-up box ONLY displays when the connection is `states[Connection.NONE]`

Comment: where to add this code?  i mean can i call this in the `$(document).ready(function() {...}` function?

Answer (score 4):

Add else to do nothing...

```js
if (navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {
    alert('Geen internet :(');
}
else {
    // nothing
};
```

Answer (score 3):

That's because you are testing the truthiness of a constant. That type
of test will always return true. What you want to use is:

```
if (navigator.network.connection.type == Connection.NONE]{
  alert('Geen internet :(');
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Check the latest documentation for cordova 2.0.0 here: http://docs.phonegap.com/en/2.0.0/cordova_connection_connection.md.html#Connection

There is a good example. You need to check for Connection.NONE or Connection.UNKNOWN - both mean no internet. Anything else means you have an internet connection of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

Solution :

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

// Wait for PhoneGap to load
// 
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

// PhoneGap is loaded and it is now safe to make calls PhoneGap methods
//
function onDeviceReady() {
    checkConnection();
}

function checkConnection() {
    var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;

    var states = {};
    states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
    states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
    states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
    states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
    states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

    alert('Connection type: ' + states[networkState]);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Try the below code.  

var networkState = navigator.network.connection.type;
var states = {};
states[Connection.UNKNOWN]  = 'Unknown connection';
states[Connection.ETHERNET] = 'Ethernet connection';
states[Connection.WIFI]     = 'WiFi connection';
states[Connection.CELL_2G]  = 'Cell 2G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_3G]  = 'Cell 3G connection';
states[Connection.CELL_4G]  = 'Cell 4G connection';
states[Connection.NONE]     = 'No network connection';

if ((states[networkState]) == states[Connection.NONE])
{
alert("Please check your internet connectivity and try again"); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm just amalgamating a couple of answers here, but I wanted something which responded to the online/offline events but also knew at the start whether there was an internet connection. I was using this in an Angular controller which broadcast about state changes, but I've removed those parts for simplicity.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
    var _curStatus = false;

    function toggleStatus(newVal) {
        console.log('Setting internet connection state to: ' + newVal);
        _curStatus = newVal;
        // My angular $broadcast went here
    }

    var conType = navigator.network.connection.type;
    toggleStatus((conType != Connection.NONE) && (conType != Connection.UNKNOWN));
    document.addEventListener("online", function() {toggleStatus(true);}, false);
    document.addEventListener("offline", function() {toggleStatus(false);}, false);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">

    // Wait for device API libraries to load
    //
    document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

    // device APIs are available
    //
    function onDeviceReady() {
        checkConnection();
    }

        function checkConnection() {
            var networkState = navigator.connection.type;

            if(navigator.connection.type == Connection.NONE) {        
        alert("No network connection.Please turn it on");
    }
        }

    </script>
```