# Cordova network information plugin regularly show offline (UNKNOWN) state

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I`m using cordova-plugin-network-information 1.2.0 "Network Information" in my ionic app but isOnline() function often returns FALSE when actually there is a connection (the problem as I can see only with mobile networks). As I have checked isOnline() returns FALSE because the getNetwork() returns UNKNOWN.
Any ideas?

Comment: android or iOS? and one more thing did you call those listeners on deviceready?

Comment: Android. Yes, I call them on deviceReady and when I`m on WIFI it works fine. When I chage connection during runtime (for ex turn off WIFI) it works fine. But when I`m over the cellular network it`s fifty-fifty... sometime works sometime not - always returns UNKNOWN network and thefore isOnline() returns FLASE.

Comment: can you do one thing immediate after the mainfest keep the network permission in Androidmanifest.xml like <manifest android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:versionCode="10000" android:versionName="1.0.0" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" package="br.com.burkard.app" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
Not sure it will work or not but you can try this.

Comment: Sounds like a hack, but how about building your own `isOnline`-method that returns true unless `getNetwork` returns `NONE`.

Comment: It`s a way, but what means the UNKNOWN state?

Comment: Of course I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" /> permission. Otherwise it will not work.

Comment: I'm experiencing the same problem on a OnePlus3 device. Did you find a solution @DmitryIsakov?

Comment: @KennethVandenBerghe, no, I did not (